# In React,How to make a page that contains two dynamic size components

Tags: css, reactjs

If data in container A collapses(minimised), Component B should increase vertically in size and appear on full page. Similarly if Component B is collapsed,component A should increase.By default,both the components have equal screen space.

Comment: Tons of possible ways to do so. Have you tried flexbox (CSS)?

Comment: No. I haven't used it.Could you please provide more explanation on that.

Comment: What you have done so far in code, share it with the post.

Comment: Hello, you should read this post about how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, it's too confuse to guide you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the parent component, you'll want to track which component is maximised. Then, pass a `maximised` prop to component A and component B, and let them set their CSS classes based on it. You could hide most of the content if you just want a mini version of the component.

Assuming you're using function components with hooks, it would look somewhat like this:

```
const Container = () => {

  // Either "A", "B" or null (equal sizes)
  const [componentMaximised, setComponentMaximised] = useState(null); 

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <A maximised={componentMaximised === "A"}/>
      <B maximised={componentMaximised === "B"}/>
    </div>
  );
};


const A = props => {
  return (
    <div className={props.maximised ? "component component-maximised" : "component"}>
      // ...
    </div>
  );
};

const B = props => {
  return (
    <div className={props.maximised ? "component component-maximised" : "component"}>
      // ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

You'll also want to pass the `setComponentMaximised` function to each component as a prop if you want them to be able to have a button to maximise and minimise themselves.

For your CSS, use `display: flex` in combination with `flex-grow` to set how the items share the space:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh; /* approx full height */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.component {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden; /* prevent contents from spilling out of component */
}

.component-maximised {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
```

Quick demo of this technique (try changing the classes manually in HTML)
https://codepen.io/gh102003/pen/MWKOQqE

You can use `flex-grow: 0` if you just want the component to take up the space it needs.

Answer (score 1):

there are tons of ways to do this, you can check how flexbox in CSS works. it should not bee very react specific, All you need to do from react is to know which component is collapsed and which is to expanded.